# R Programming: Condition giving always TRUE

Tags: r

I am trying to make the last column get the data from the 5th column. If the character is "M" it should do something, if "F" something else, here's my code:

```
wd="c:/users/Youssef/Documents/Fares/R/employes.txt";
setwd(wd);
employes=read.table("c:/users/Youssef/Documents/Fares/R/employes.txt", sep=" ")
employes["PRIMES"] <- NA
x = "M"
ifelse(employes$V3==x, employes$PRIMES <- employes$V5*2, employes$PRIMES <- employes$V5*3)
employes
```

And here is my text file:

```
AD5522 42 M 42000 10
BR4230 39 F 38000 12
CC0563 39 F 35000 14
DL3222 24 M 28000 2
EM0157 43 M 38000 15
FG5441 62 M 45000 28
GG0575 27 M 44000 4
HD4410 55 F 30000 2
IA1203 32 F 28000 4
JO9876 24 F 24000 2
KJ3481 42 M 40000 8
LL1101 34 M 42000 10
MM0157 56 M 87000 15
ZD5431 34 M 54000 28
SF0325 73 M 33000 4
LK4200 61 F 23000 2
PI1243 26 F 74000 4
NB9809 42 F 64000 2
XF3111 71 M 12000 8
AL1190 23 M 53000 10
```

What I want to do is create a new column titled PRIMES and put the value of the 5th column double it and put it there if it's M, triple it if it's F. But what my code does is triple everything as if it reads only the first M and multiply every number by 3 and put it on the column PRIMES

Comment: It is not the correct syntax of `ifelse`.

Comment: I think the 2 first lines are useless so don't mind them

Comment: @Pascal It's working if I print ("Male") and print ("Female") Instead of replacing the data on the column. The only thing is that it prints Male and Female 1 extra time before printing it for the whole rows.

Comment: See answer below for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ifelse` produces a vector.  You want this:

```
employes$PRIMES <- ifelse(employes$V3==x,  employes$V5*2, employes$V5*3)
```

Or more simply and efficiently (Thanks @Richard)

```
employes$PRIMES <- employes$V5 * ifelse(employes$V3==x, 2, 3)
```

This creates a vector of `2`'s and `3`'s to use in the multiplication.

Comment: `employes$V5 * ifelse(employes$V3==x,  2, 3)` is the same thing in a bit nicer package

Comment: I like `employes <- transform(employes, PRIMES=V5*ifelse(V3==x,2,3))`

Comment: or (just joking) `PRIMES=V5*(3-as.numeric(V3==x))`

Comment: @BenBolker - Why joking?  `V5 * (3 - (V3 == "M"))` seems like a really good one to me.

Comment: These sorts of solutions are too clever/tricky for me.  I don't find such code easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dplyr way:

```
library(dplyr)

data = 
  employes %>%
  setNames(c("ID", "age", "gender", "long", "short"))

gender_key = data_frame(
  gender = c("M", "F"),
  multiplier = c(2, 3) )

result = 
  data %>%
  left_join(gender_key) %>%
  mutate(new_short = short * multiplier)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know who gave you a bad feedback... I can't upvote for certain reasons.