# If statement is always true regardless of condition

Tags: r, if-statement, apply

I think I have the same issue posted here: [R Programming: Condition giving always TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054709/r-programming-condition-giving-always-true) but I do not know how to apply the answer to my situation.

The if statement below searches for a match in the major_allele column for REF and vice-versa. The problem is that it always evaluates to true as shown by the rows with astericks. The previous answer at the above link stated that ifelse always produces a vector so I am guessing that it is only looking at the first observation, evaluates to true and then moves to doing the same across all rows. However, I would like it to go row-by-row. Below new_gwas_a1 is created but from the REF column for all rows but it should be false for the rows with asterisk.

```
for (i in files){
rsid.tmp  <- read.table(i, header = TRUE, sep=" ", stringsAsFactors = 
FALSE, fill = TRUE)


rsid.tmp$new_gwas_a1 <-if((sapply(lapply(rsid.tmp$REF, grepl, 
x=rsid.tmp$major_allele),any))
                || (sapply(lapply(rsid.tmp$major_allele, grepl, 
x=rsid.tmp$REF),any)))
        {rsid.tmp$REF}

new_file <- sub("(\\.txt)$", "_updated\\1", i)
write.table(rsid.tmp, new_file, quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)


REF ALT minor_allele_frequency  minor_allele    major_allele     
new_gwas_a1
A   G   0.000219914 G   A   A
C   T   0.0144844   T   C   C
C   T   0.0445486   T   C   C
C   T   0.00647968  T   C   C
C   T   0.222656    T   C   C
**A G,T 0.12189     A   G   A
**A G,T 0.305252    A   G   A
C   T   0.00210762  T   C   C
C   A   0.00139373  A   C   C
```

I was also receiving this warning previously which hasn't shown again since but I wonder if the issue is related. Warning message: In if (sapply(lapply(rsid.tmp$REF, grepl, x = rsid.tmp$minor_allele), : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I tried this same code directly in R and it seems to work. See below please

```
> a <- c("TGTGTGT")
> b <- c("AC")
> c <- c("A")
> d <- c("AGTGTG,ATGTGT")
> e <- c("TG")

> if((sapply(lapply(a, grepl, x=c),any)) || (sapply(lapply(c, grepl, 
x=a),any))) {print(Yes)}

> if((sapply(lapply(b, grepl, x=c),any)) || (sapply(lapply(c, grepl, 
x=b),any))) {print("Yes")}
[1] "Yes"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with your last question, I'm a little bit puzzled and I'm not really sure what you are trying to do.

So, let's say your data looks like this:

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 6
  REF   ALT   minor_allele_frequency minor_allele major_allele new_gwas_a1
  <chr> <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>      
1 A     G                   0.000220 G            A            A          
2 C     T                   0.0145   T            C            C          
3 C     T                   0.0445   T            C            C          
4 C     T                   0.00648  T            C            C          
5 C     T                   0.223    T            C            C          
6 A     G,T                 0.122    A            G            A          
7 A     G,T                 0.305    A            G            A          
8 C     T                   0.00211  T            C            C          
9 C     A                   0.00139  A            C            C
```

Now we create two new columns: `match_REF_major` is `TRUE`, if the content of major_allele is found in column `REF`. `match_major_REF` is the other way round.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(match_REF_major = str_detect(REF, major_allele),
         match_major_REF = str_detect(major_allele, REF))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 8
  REF   ALT   minor_allele_frequency minor_allele major_allele new_gwas_a1 match_REF_major match_major_REF
  <chr> <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       <lgl>           <lgl>          
1 A     G                   0.000220 G            A            A           TRUE            TRUE           
2 C     T                   0.0145   T            C            C           TRUE            TRUE           
3 C     T                   0.0445   T            C            C           TRUE            TRUE           
4 C     T                   0.00648  T            C            C           TRUE            TRUE           
5 C     T                   0.223    T            C            C           TRUE            TRUE           
6 A     G,T                 0.122    A            G            A           FALSE           FALSE          
7 A     G,T                 0.305    A            G            A           FALSE           FALSE          
8 C     T                   0.00211  T            C            C           TRUE            TRUE           
9 C     A                   0.00139  A            C            C           TRUE            TRUE
```

If necessary, it's easy to combine those two new columns into one column. But this way isn't very stable, since the content of `major_allele` and `REF` are interpreted as a regex-pattern. This, for example, causes an error, if `REF` contains `**A` instead of `A`.